# SVN - Get all the commit messages between given two revisions and folder URL

Tags: git, bash, svn, version-control

I'm looking for a SVN command (or some bash file) that get two different revision numbers and URL to a folder and returns all the commit messages between those revision.

Example:

```
$svn getLog 9558 9583 http://someurl/projects/myProject/trunk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-r` option of `svn log` with a `from:to` range](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html):

```
svn log -r 9558:9583 http://someurl/projects/myProject/trunk
```

Answer (score 1):

check this option

svn log --verbose -r258:106 https://repoAddress/trunk